# Should it be "how about he take" or "how about he took" in the following?

Tags: grammar, tense

This is in the past tense (third-person). Should I use *took* or *take* and why?

> There was someone outside the door. How about he *took/take* a peek
> through the peephole?

Note: *he* here is the observer.

Comment: The two sentences don't really make sense together.  *How about...?* is a suggestion, but if the events are taking place in the past, how are you suggesting something to him now?

Comment: If you are describing the observer's thoughts, you could get round the problem by using _How about taking..._

Comment: If you want to avoid the tone that you, the author, are suggesting something to the character, you could phrase it as the character's internal thought, which probably becomes subjunctive: "What if he were to take a peek...?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These sentences don't go together.  The first is a past tense narrative, the writer is telling a story to the reader.

The second is a suggestion, to the reader, apparently to pass on the person outside the door.  But that doesn't work, becuase the person outside the door is in the story, and not real.  And the story is past tense so not in the same time as the reader.

If you continue with the narrative you could say

> There was someone outside the door. My husband was standing next to me. I suggested that he take a peek through the peephole.

This is a subjunctive. "I suggested that he *do* something" (and not does)

You can make suggestions with "how about":  How about you do something. It is also subjunctive, but the subjunctive form of of the verb is the same as the *you* form of the verb, and the same as a bare infinitive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But assuming I want to keep the second sentence as it is, should it be "take" or "took"?

Comment: I've edited to demonstrate that I've already answered that.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for the detailed answer!